# How to webscrape no next page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying scrape data from this website https://publishednotices.asic.gov.au/browsesearch-notices/

The issue is that there is no next page and the website is dynamic. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# open url
browser.get("https://publishednotices.asic.gov.au/browsesearch-notices/")

for page in range(3,7):
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(f"td:nth-child({page}) a").click()

    # get data

    time.sleep(1)

tmp = True
while tmp:
    for page in range(4, 9):
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector(f"td:nth-child({page}) a").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            tmp = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next page number element and click on it using `element.click()`